# Why Pointers to Undefined Structs are Sometimes Illegal in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Why is

```
void foo(T*);
```

illegal in both C and C++ (because `T` is undefined), whereas

```
void foo(struct T*);
```

is valid, even though it still does not *define* `T`? Is there any situation in which it makes a semantic difference to the caller whether `T` is a struct or some other type (class/enum/typedef/etc.)?

Comment: just out of curiosity, why would  you need to take a pointer to an undefined struct?  If it's undefined, then why not just take in a void* ?

Comment: @John: Because I haven't included the appropriate header file for the definition of `T` yet, but I still want my code to compile because I don't see why it matters what `T` is.

Comment: @John: This is commonplace. Why bring in a [potentially heavy] definition when all you need [at that point in your code] is a declaration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C, because pointer to structs (any struct) all have the same width and alignment properties

> 6.2.5/27 ([C99 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf))
>
> A pointer to void shall have the  same  representation
>          and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type.
>          Similarly, pointers to qualified or unqualified versions  of
>          compatible  types  shall  have  the  same representation and
>          alignment requirements.  All pointers to structure  types
>          shall   have   the   same   representation   and   alignment
>          requirements as each other.  All  pointers  to  union  types
>          shall   have   the   same   representation   and   alignment
>          requirements as each other.  Pointers to  other  types  need
>          not  have the same representation or alignment requirements.

---

Pointers to anything, on the other hand, may have distinct width and/or alignment properties (void*, function pointers, unsigned char*, ...)

Comment: @pmg: I can't imagine why a pointer to a union might, for example, ever be different from a pointer to a struct, but if it could hypothetically be the case then that makes perfect sense. :-) Thanks!

Comment: @pmg: However, that raises another question: is a `void*` defined as pointing to an undefined `struct`? Or can it also hold a pointer to a function, enum, union, etc.? I'm asking because if a `void*` can hold a pointer to *anything*, then the compiler can just treat `T*` as `void*` for the call, right?

Comment: @Mehrdad: If you read again, you might notice that there is a huge difference in that in the second case, the argument is guaranteed to be a pointer to a type, while in the first it is not. `T` might be defined as `int T = 5;`, and then `void foo( T * x );` will be ill formed, but the addition of `struct` guarantees that it *is* a type.

Comment: This explains why forward declaration works. However, IMO, it does not answer the actual question posed.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I've pasted the full 6.2.5/27 paragraph now. teh way I interpret it there are 4 groups: void and char pointer, struct pointers, union pointers, and all other pointers. A pointer to a `T` does not belong to any one group.

Comment: @pmg: Just curious, is that from the C standard or the C++ standard? Microsoft's C reference says that `A pointer to void can be converted to or from a pointer to any type, without restriction or loss of information.`... I'm taking it as they're wrong?

Comment: @Mehrdad: your questions all boil down to: why doesn't the compiler guess my intentions? But compilers never guess. the why doesn't matter, they just don't do it.

Comment: Ah! It's the C Standard, sorry (I have no idea about C++). The reason `void*` is compatible with pointers to any object is because the Standard says so: the implementation must make sure its representation and alignment are greater than absolutely needed to guarantee compatability.

Comment: @pmg: So can't the compiler just pretend -- for declaration purposes -- that I'd said `void*` instead?

Comment: @Mehrdad: No! if `void*` requirements make it have a different representation than `T*` then you have a mismatch. About the same error as casting the return value of `malloc()` :)

Comment: @Tomolak: Quite the opposite. This answer is the _only_ one to answer the question.

Comment: That would constitute a guess that `void*` is an appropriate substitution. Since compilers don't guess, obviously that is not an option.

Comment: @Troubadour: Hardly. It doesn't even _mention_ the `void foo(T*)` case. The OP is comparing this code against a forward declaration and asking for an explanation of the difference.

Comment: @Tomalak: The OP wants to know why `void foo(T*)` can't be used to declare `foo` as a function that takes a pointer to something. This answer explains that not all pointers are the same i.e. the "something" matters.

Comment: @Troubadour: And completely ignores that the compiler _does not know that `T` is a type_ in that code. That's the **real** cause of the error case. It's a really simple parsing thing.

Comment: For a C++ take on this, look into how overloaded functions work, specifically with regard to the linker.

Comment: @Tomalak: The fact that the compiler doesn't know `T` is a type in the code is not really a problem, because the parser shouldn't care what `T` is -- **unless** not all pointers are the same, which seems to be what the standard is saying, hence why this answer makes sense. A convincing answer would show that it's a code generation issue and not just a parsing issue.
@pmg: But if all `void*`s satisfy the requirements of `T*`s, why can't the compiler place more restrictions and satisfy everything?
@Troubadour: **Exactly** correct, that's what I was asking! :)

Comment: @Dennis: Overloading doesn't seem like it would be a problem, because it's only a problem when the function is **called**, and by that point, `T` would be declared.

Comment: @Mehrdad: As I've said repeatedly, `T` could just as well be the name of a variable, in which case it doesn't matter whether all pointers are the same or not. The language _chooses_ not to make for you the assumption that you meant for `T` to be a type, because who is the compiler to decide what you really meant when you made your mistake? C++ chooses not to second guess programmer mistakes. Thank god! (It's interesting to note that C, in many cases, assumes `int` in declarations if you omit the type. Glad that was changed for C++!)

Comment: @Tomalak: Can you provide an example where `T` is not a valid type name, where *if the compiler pretended like it was, **it would introduce an ambiguity/bug***?

Comment: @Mehrdad: You already asked me this, and I already answered it. It's really simple. If I write `void foo(Blah*)`, on its own, and `Blah` has not been previously introduced, but I meant for it not to be a type and had completely messed up, then I would prefer that C++ not just guess (wrongly) for me that `Blah` should be a type. That's why.

Comment: @Tomalak: It's implicit in the question that T is not something that would cause the line to be ill-formed.

Comment: @Troubadour: That's highly subjective, and the C++ standard agrees with me. That's why it _doesn't_ make the assumption.

Comment: @Tomalak: For example, I could very well ask, Why does the compiler even need a declaration? Why doesn't it just pretend like `foo((int)i)` also declares `foo` to take in an `int`? However, the answer is that *if `foo` is overloaded to take a `long` instead, it would not be possible to generate correct code*. The answer is **not** "it's a parsing issue" or "second-guessing the programmer", but a complete ambiguity that would be **impossible** to resolve without more info. I was looking for something similar here.

Comment: @Mehrdad: why must T have been declared by then? You want the compiler to guess here that you are dealing with a struct, and function arguments aren't the only place forward declarations of structs are useful.  Why wouldnt the compiler guess in those other places as well?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Well, I provide that answer in my answer. It may not produce an ambiguity in the code, but that still doesn't mean that the language should just guess at what you meant to write. And.. it doesn't. C++ never does; that's part of its mandate.

Comment: @Dennis: Depends. In fact, it doesn't need to be declared if all you really want is to work with `T*`. But in that case, like before, it shouldn't matter what `T` is, because we're just working with pointers. But if you actually need to work with `T`, that's when you need to declare it, and hence why it must be declared.

Comment: @Mehrdad: here you're "just" writing the prototype. The function definition is written somewhere else. The prototype and the definition must match (remember `malloc`?) ... if the definition uses `void*` all's well; if the definition uses `T*`, writing the prototype with `void*` will cause troubles.

Comment: @Tomalak: Yes, so your answer basically says it's a grammar ambiguity rather than a code ambiguity, which is of course completely valid but which isn't quite convincing, because it doesn't explain why it has to be that way. Hence @Troubadour's reply, and why this answer seems to be more convincing. :)

Comment: @Mehrdad: The most convincing answer is the answer that best fits with your preconceptions, not necessarily with the truth. Ambiguities aside, C++ _does not make assumptions for the user_. Simple as that!

Comment: @pmg: But `malloc` **returns** a pointer, not take it as a parameter. That's a different issue, because that could definitely cause problems. But why would it be a problem here? If you have a function that takes in a `T*`, and you pass it a pointer that has *more* restrictions, why would that be problematic?

Comment: @Tomalak: The thing is, my issue wasn't "Why doesn't my code compile?" but "Why were C/C++ designed this way?". Your answer states the fact that it doesn't compile, and states the reason why, but it doesn't say what the problem would be if the restriction was removed -- this answer, on the other hand, explains the problem:  not all pointers might be the same on a given platform, so the compiler simply **can't** generate valid code. Now I'm just trying to understand whether or not the compiler could pretend it was a `void*`, but the answer otherwise explains the root cause of the problem.

Comment: @Mehrdad: And I just answered that question. C++'s mandate is not to make assumptions for the user. That's _just how it is_. I really don't understand why we keep coming back to the potential for practical ambiguities, when they're not really particularly relevant. But unfortunately you seem to have been convinced otherwise; I've stated my case and that'll do for now!

Comment: @Tomalak: If it helps if I rephrase it, my question, in a single word, was: "why?". To which "that's just how it is" isn't a very convincing answer. :\

Comment: @Mehrdad: Repeating the question won't change the answer. C++ chooses to let the user see an error and decide what his/her mistake was, rather than second-guessing what he/she might have meant. That's _it_. It's a decision made by the people who designed the language.

Comment: @Tomalak: I'm not sure what you're trying to get at, but I personally found this answer more convincing, because it explained the root cause rather than just saying "that's how it is". If someone else finds yours more convincing then great! That's why we can put multiple answers on this site. :]

Comment: Suppose, for the sake of argument, that `void*` needs 4 bytes, and that `T*` needs 2 bytes. When you call the function, the compiler sees the prototype and puts 4 bytes on the stack ... the function definition takes 2 bytes from the stack to get the `T*`. If the function was defined with `void*` and converted the pointer in the function body all would be ok. *And this doesn't happen automatically because C tries to be as efficient as possible --- why pass 4 bytes when 2 suffice?*

Comment: @Mehrdad: Again, whether or not you find it convincing is only down to your preconceptions. In my professional judgement, the rationale given in this answer is _not_ the reason that the first snippet errors (rather than assuming a forward declaration). I seem to be unable to "convince" you of this, so... I give up! Good question, BTW.

Comment: @Tomalak: Like I mentioned, *of course* it's not why it errors. It errors because, like you said, the standard said so. The issue was *why* did the standard say so, hence why I accepted this answer (just trying to figure out right now the details of what would happen if the compiler assumed a `void*`, that's all). And thanks!! The discussions are really great too! :)

Comment: The answer that doesn't say anything about why the standard **actually** says so *sigh*

Comment: @pmg: I completely *did **not*** realize that `sizeof(void*)` doesn't have to be equal to `sizeof(T*)`, I just thought it was an issue with alignment and things like that (I missed the word `width` entirely in your answer)... that explains a lot. Thank you!! :D

Comment: @Tomalak: Yeah it doesn't, because that wasn't what the question was asking for, sorry if it was unclear. :(

Comment: @Mehrdad: Wheeewwwwwwwwwww this was tough :D "pointer representation" includes number of bytes, padding bits, ..., ... glad we finally sorted it out.

Comment: @pmg: By the way, I **really** like the first sentence in your profile. Strange tendencies like that are good. :D

Comment: @Mehrdad: It's not even just width - theoretically, the platform ABI is allowed to say things like _"When calling a function, the first int pointer is placed in the %pi0 register, and the first void pointer is placed in the %pv0 register."_

Answer (score 6):

`void foo(struct T*);` simultaneously functions as a forward-declaration of `struct T` within that scope, so it's safe to name a pointer to it.

In `void foo(T*)` there is no telling what `T` is supposed to be. If it turns out to be the name of a variable rather than a type, then the line of code is ill-formed. C++ needs more information before it can say that the line of code is valid.

Comment: @Doug: Interesting about the forward-declaration. But why does it make what `T` is, when all we need to know is that we're taking in a pointer?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Because if `T` is not a type (and, remember, "we" don't know _what_ it is) then the line of code is ill-formed. [I have added this to my answer.]

Comment: @Tomalak: So it's just there to make the grammar more strict, rather than for any implementation/ambiguity reasons?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Essentially. I'd say all three factors you list are inherently entwined. :)

Comment: @Mehrdad: chomp said it best in his answer: "If the mere occurrence of a previously unseen symbol semantically implied a forward type declaration, I think we'd be in a lot of trouble."

Comment: @Tomalak: At first @chomp's answer sounded great, but I can't think of any troublesome examples... do you happen to have any?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Coming up with counter-examples is besides the point; the mere fact that they may mathematically exist is reason enough for C++ not to allow this. (And, in fact, it's clear that it would be undesirable behaviour. If `T` is in fact not a type because you made a mistake in your code, you _want_ the error.)

Answer (score 2):

```
struct T
```

acts as a [forward declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) of T. You're promising the compiler you'll define it later. If you actually did something on T or tried to instantiate it, you'd have problems:

```
  struct T t1; //error, incomplete type
  struct T* t2; // ok
  t2->foo     // error, incomplete type
```

Just

```
 T
```

is an arbitrary identifier. Is it a variable? Is it a function? The language provides no facility to forward declare without adding `struct` or `class` in front of the variable.

Comment: Interesting. But why does it make what `T` is, when all we need to know is that we're taking in a pointer?

Answer (score 1):

`struct T` declares `T` as a `struct` even when it appears in a larger declaration, i.e. the declaration of `foo`. The type is incomplete but that doesn't matter when it's used to declarat a pointer function parameter.

Without the `struct` the compiler doesn't know anything about what `T` is supposed to be.

If `T` had previously been declared as a `struct` then `void foo(T*)` would be allowed in C++ but not C because the names of `struct`s don't automatically become type names although you can declared a `typedef` with an identical name in C if you want to.

Comment: Yes, but my question is, *why does that matter*? i.e. what difference does it make what `T` is, when all we need to know is that we're taking in a pointer?

Comment: @Mehrdad: I'm not sure I understand what you're driving at. Those are the language rules. Any identifier - object, function or type - needs to be declared before it is used and the `struct` makes the use of `T` a declaration.

Comment: Because pointer to structs (any struct) all have the same width and alignment properties (6.2.5/27 `"All pointers to structure types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other."`). Pointers to anything, on the other hand, may have distinct width and/or alignment properties (void*, function pointers, unsigned char*, ...)

Comment: @pmg: So a pointer to a struct and a pointer to a union/enum/etc. could have different alignment properties?